# I'm having trouble accessing an array value in Flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter

In my code I have a dropdown that receives the values ​​from a list but these values ​​are within the variable value of the dropdown and I can't access the first or second value. Follow the code:

```
List<int> cilindro1 = [4145, 2100];
List<int> cilindro2 = [4405, 2085];
List<int> cilindro3 = [4140, 2095];


child: DropdownButton<String>(
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('Cilindro 1'),
            value: '$cilindro1',
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('Cilindro 2'),
            value: '${cilindro2}',
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('Cilindro 3'),
            value: '${cilindro3}',
          ),
        ],
        onChanged: (String value) {
          setState(() {
            _valoresArray = value;
          });
        },
```

The variable that contains the values ​​is _valoresArray and I can't choose the index from it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using **substring**.

```
var peso = value.substring(1, 5);
var volume = value.substring(7, 11);
_peso = peso;
_volume = volume;
```